# Strike through a word in a string PowerPoint interop

Tags: c#, interop

I have 2 PowerPoints one original and one edited. I each PowerPoint I have a textbox that contains a number of words. The idea is to find any words added or deleted from the original PowerPoint in the edited and put them in a list. I then want to put a strike though these words that have been added or deleted but I can't access any of the properties I need as I have a string and not a TextFrame. Any ideas how I could strike through the words? E.g original "This Text" edited "This New Text" outcome "This New Text".

My code is as fallows

```
  List<int> originalShapesListID = new List<int>();
    List<int> editedShapesListID = new List<int>();
    List<int> originalListID = new List<int>();
    List<int> editedListID = new List<int>();
    List<Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape> originalList = new List<Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape>();
    List<Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape> editList = new List<Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape>();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape editedShpID;
    List<Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape> originalListWords = new List<Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape>();
    List<char> editListWords = new List<char>();
    editedShpID = null;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape originalShpID;
    long editedShapeID;
    long originalShapeID;
    editedShapeID = 0;
    originalShapeID = 0;
    originalShpID = null;
    originalShp = null;
    editShp = null;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.TextFrame txtFrame;
    char delimiter = Convert.ToChar(" ");
    List<string> one = new List<string>();
    List<string> two = new List<string>();
    int indexOfWord = 0;
```

Getting all Text

```
String pps = "";

foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Slide slide in Originalslides)
{
    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape originalShape in slide.Shapes)
    {
        originalShp = originalShape;
        if (originalShape.HasTextFrame == Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue)
        {
            var textFrame = originalShape.TextFrame;
            if (textFrame.HasText == Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue)
            {
                var textRange = textFrame.TextRange;
                pps += originalShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text;
                foreach (char word in pps)
                {

                    l.Add(word);
                    Debug.WriteLine(word);
                }


            }
        }
        originalShapesListID.Add(originalShape.Id);
        originalShapeID = originalShape.Id;
        originalList.Add(originalShape);
    }

    originalListID.Add(slide.SlideID);
}

foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Slide slide in EditedSlides)
{
    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape editShape in slide.Shapes)
    {
        editShp = editShape;
        if (editShape.HasTextFrame == Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue)
        {

            var textFrame = editShape.TextFrame;
            if (textFrame.HasText == Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue)
            {
                var textRange = textFrame.TextRange;
                pps += editShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text;
                foreach (char word in pps)
                {

                    l.Add(word);
                    Debug.WriteLine(word);
                }


            }
        }

        editedShapesListID.Add(editShape.Id);
        editedShapeID = editShape.Id;
        editList.Add(editShape);




    }

    editedListID.Add(slide.SlideID);


}
```

Checking if there is an added or deleted word

```
var q = from original in originalList
        join editedTmp in editList on original.Id equals editedTmp.Id into g
        from edited in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new
        {
            original,
            edited
        };



//foreach  through both lists
foreach (var item in q)
{


    List<string> diff;

    var originalString = item.original.TextFrame.TextRange.Text;
var editString = item.edited.TextFrame.TextRange.Text;

var firstStringList = originalString.Split(delimiter).ToList();

var secondStringList = editString.Split(delimiter).ToList();

    if (secondStringList.Count() > firstStringList.Count())
    {
        diff = secondStringList.Except(firstStringList).ToList();
        //change to blue for added word

    }
    else
    {

            diff = firstStringList.Except(secondStringList).ToList();


            // change to red for deleted word
        }
}
```

Updates section

```
        foreach (var word in firstStringList)
    {
            //check if word matches
            if (secondStringList.IndexOf(word, indexOfWord) == -1)
            {

               // add word to second string in the correct position 
                secondStringList.Insert(indexOfWord + indexOfWord, word);



            }
            indexOfWord++;


    }

        indexOfWord=0;
        // Join the secondStringList to make 1 string separated by the space character
        item.edited.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = string.Join(" ", secondStringList);
```

Comment: you should use instead of secondstringlist a list with a new object which contains the word and the status of the word (e.g. status could be: unchanged, changed, deleted). Finally you can format the words by the status.

Comment: If I do add all the words to a list with a new object and I created an enum for unchanged, changed and deleted how could I format the words with a strikethrough?

Comment: you code snipplet doesn't show how do you create the output. I would expect that you go back to the shape object and format the text. When you browse in the object model you will find the property "Text" [Object model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff746239.aspx) from textrange object. This object has e.g. a property called "Font" [Font object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff745932.aspx)

Comment: @ChristineRoss I basically want to put a strike though every word in the diff list however I can't convert it to a text range because it is a `List<string>`

Comment: This will not work, you can not assign attributes to a simple stringlist. How would see if it is striked when you don't print it out?

By the way I think your search algorithm is not working, because you have to check if the text pattern continues later. What is when one, or two or three words are deleted? What when words are added?

Comment: @ChristineRoss I do print it out. Please see updates section in my code. Here I'm finding any words that do not match and then adding it to a string e.g original textbox "This is Old" edited textbox "This is New" Printed output "This is Old New" I want to strike out the word "Old"

Comment: So you can use "item.edited.TextFrame.TextRange.Text" which has a property called "font" where you can format the single words, please see in my above link for details in the powerpoint object model. But you have to know which word to format

Comment: I forgot: Powerpoint has no macro recorder, but word and excel have. So you can record a macro for inserting text, selecting a word format it with strikethrough..